# How do I load prepared message, with attachments, into user's default mail client?

Tags: c#, email, outlook, mapi

How do I load prepared message, with attachments, into user's default mail client?

I went looking around for answers to that, and found:

- Using Process.Start() with a "mailto:" url won't work, because mailto: doesn't support attachments (except in Outlook, and I can't rely on Outlook being the default client.)
- This [Code Project MAPI wrapper](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17561/Programmatically-adding-attachments-to-emails-in-C) won't work, because it apparently blocks the app.
- Then there's [this MAPI Wrapper](http://www.vbusers.com/codecsharp/codeget.asp?ThreadID=71&PostID=1), which apparently does not block the app, but it changes the current directory, and that breaks a number of things in our app, some of which are running in different threads, so I can't rely on just changing it back.
- And after trying out the above, and discovering the current directory issue, I ran across [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stephen_griffin/archive/2008/06/24/mapi-and-the-current-directory.aspx?Redirected=true), which blamed the issue on the MAPI stub library,
- And that directed me [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms528324%28EXCHG.10%29.aspx), which pointed out that the MAPI stub library is deprecated.

Which leaves me asking:

Is there a way, in a C# application, to create an email message that includes attachments, and load it into the user's default mail client, that does not depend upon the client being Outlook, doesn't block the UI of the app while running, doesn't change the current directory of the app out from underneath it, and doesn't rely on deprecated and soon-to-be-removed system libraries?

Comment: Basically something like `Right Click > Send To > Mail Recipient` in the Windows Explorer, right?

Comment: Are you trying to create a message in one of the fodlers (e.g. Inbox or Sent Items) or display a message to the user? If your app breaks when the current directory is changed, you have bigger problems than creating a message...

Comment: Can't you use the code project MAPI wrapper and put it in a background thread?  Then there is no blocking.

Comment: What @DmitryStreblechenko said.  Do you want to email the user? Have the user send an email?  Simply display it to them?  Launch their client?  There's different answers for all of those.

Comment: I want to create a message, and display it in their default mail client, so that they can edit it, add additional recipients, etc.

Comment: If you want to support most mail clients, you would need to do that through Simple MAPI. If that breaks your app because the current directory changes, you would need to fix thaat. And IMHO it is worth fixing regardless of any MAPi issues.

Comment: The app accesses certain files via paths that are specified in a config file. If these are absolute paths, the app has no dependency on current directory. But the implementors insist on configuring things with a relative path, claiming that one, it's too much trouble to have a separate configuration file for every client machine, and two, it's too much trouble to configure every client machine to have the same path to the shared files. So they use relative paths in the config file, and set the working directory in the shortcut. In other words, there's no coding fix for the problem.

Comment: BTW - Simple MAPI is deprecated.

Comment: @JeffDege After a couple hours of googling, I'm at the exact same place you were at--same links and everything. Did you manage to find a solution? (Seems like it should be an easy problem, doesn't it?)

Comment: I found no solution, and was told that it wasn't a functionality we needed to supply, in our current release, so worry about it later.

Comment: Grrr. This is exactly the problem I am having. I just want to be able to pre-populate a mailmessage object with all the properties of the email (from, to, subject, body, and an attachment file) and present it to the web client to decide whether to send it as is, or edit the email before hitting send! Surely there must be a way